# Name link out sheet

Tags: excel

I have a excel file with vba. This file have 2 sheet.
All name defined has "'refers to' ='sheetname'!$B$2"
But only one name "'refers to' =info!$A$1" with value link to another file with same path this file.
(no sheet have name info)
Question: How I can find cell to edit value?

Comment: Please have a look on [ask] a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a quick scan down the **Refers To** column of Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager is not producing results then you are going to have to enumerate all of the [Workbook.Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.names.aspx) collection. This includes all defined names in the workbook; both workbook scope and worksheet scope.

```
Sub find_named_range()
    Dim n As Long, rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        For n = 1 To .Names.Count
            If CBool(InStr(1, LCase(.Names(n).RefersTo), "info")) Then
                Debug.Print .Names(n).Name          '<~~ the defined name
                Debug.Print .Names(n).RefersTo      '<~~ the cell location
                Debug.Print .Names(n).RefersToRange '<~~ the value in the cell
                'exit for
            End If
        Next n
    End With
End Sub
```

If it is guaranteed to be only one then you might want to uncomment the `Exit For` command and halt the loop after finding the first but I would probably let it run a few extra ms just to be sure.

Comment: Debug.Print .Names(n).RefersTo it show the Name i want check:
'info!$A$1'

Comment: One more note:
I can write i cell with formula:
=info!A1
it show address of mdb files.